# Problema para colocar os resultados de um bot no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, chatbot, openpyxl

O bot é feito para ver se algum pdf é valido ou não, se for valido quero que escreva no excel o nome do pdf se esta valido ou invalido e uma versão(nessa versão pode ser um sequencia de números)
def olhar_banner(driver, self):
time.sleep(3)
resultado = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'titulobannervalid')
texto = resultado.text

```
    wb = load_workbook("PlTeste.xlsx")
    ws = wb.active
    bot_page = wb.create_sheet('BOT')
    bot_page.append(['Nome do DOC', 'VERSÃO', 'SITUAÇÃO'])

    diretorio = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'PilhaDeTestes')
    arquivos = [arq for arq in os.listdir(diretorio) if arq.endswith('.pdf')]
    num_arquivos = len(arquivos)
    for row in bot_page.iter_rows(min_row=2):
        ws.append([cell.value for cell in row])

    if texto == 'Documento com assinaturas válidas':
        print("Assinatura válida, registrando resultado...")
        for nome_doc in arquivos:
            versao = num_arquivos
            bot_page.append([nome_doc, versao, "VÁLIDA"])

    elif texto == 'Documentos com assinaturas reprovadas':
        print("Assinatura inválida, registrando resultado...")
        for nome_doc in arquivos:
            versao = num_arquivos
            bot_page.append([nome_doc, versao, "INVÁLIDA"])

    else:
        raise ValueError('Erro ao encontrar texto do banner')
```

Comment: Está dando algum erro? Qual? Onde?